# How can I create an app shell using Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, progressive-web-apps

I've been in the process of improving considerably the performance of my react application (Created with create-react-app). I'm hosting my application in AWS S3 and I'd like to avoid server-side rendering so I can leverage the hassle-free world of static hosting. To make the long story short, I'd like to extract the app's shell (Meaning The footer, header, and sidebar into a static content, the latter would be rehydrated and supercharged with more details once the user logs in), and the terms of service, registration, and about pages to static. Then the application would be entirely dynamic in its nature (including the main index entry).

I tried using react-snap but it's having trouble rendering the service worker, and it doesn't give me the full experience as this application is behind an authentication wall (I had to make some compromises like asking manually the user to login, which I'd like this process to be automatic).

I saw that Gatsby can fit the needs that I'm looking for (My App is already architected in Reach Router). I don't want (for now) any other features, just the pre-rendering of the app shell, about, terms of service, and registration pages.

How can I achieve this?

I have already booted up the app in Gatsby, and loaded the main page. But if I change a route, I get hit by a 404 (which is normal, as I have not defined them inside pages). I checked [the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-client-only-routes) and some starters, but I can't seem to find my answer.

Here's my only file in `/src/pages`.

```
// src/pages/index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Root from '../views/Root';

export default () => <Root />;
```

Where `<Root />` is my entire app.
(I know the about page is not going to be static as it hasn't been defined inside `/src/pages`)

I tried adding this in `gatsby-node.js` so I could catch all the routes as dynamic, except the about page, but it hasn't worked.

```
// gatsby-node.js
// Includes everything but the about page.
const regex = /^((?!(\/about)).)*$/;
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  // Only update the `/app` page.
  if (page.path.match(regex)) {
    // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
    // with corresponding routes only on the client.
    page.matchPath = '/*';
    // Update the page.
    createPage(page);
  }
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gatsby plugin "gatsby-plugin-offline" which will not only setup your website to work offline and cache your requests, it also comes with built in app shell functionality.

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/?=offline

From the link above:

> App shell and server logs Server logs (like from Netlify analytics) may show a large number of pageviews to a route like
> /offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html, this is a result of
> gatsby-plugin-offline adding an app shell to the page. The app shell
> is a minimal amount of user interface that can be cached offline for
> reliable performance loading on repeat visits. The shell can be loaded
> from the cache, and the content of the site loaded into the shell by
> the service worker.